# Pass the same environment variable to two processes in one line

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Is there a way to pass an environment variable to two processes that are started in one line in bash? I want to execute two processes in the same command line

```
# these are ways to execute two processes in the same line
exec1 & exec2
exec1 && exec2
exec1 || exec2
exec1; exec2
```

And this is the way to pass an environment variable to a process:

```
VAR=value exec
```

How can I combine both?

```
# this is not enough because exec2 does not see VAR
VAR=value exec1 & exec2
```

I know the way to do it with `export`:

```
export VAR=value; exec1 & exec2; unset EXPORT
```

Is there another way to do it without export?

Comment: Not unless you wrap the two commands in a function. Pre-command environment changes only work for *simple* commands.

Comment: Also, note that your workaround is not equivalent; if `VAR` had a value before, it no longer does after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this: Scope the export to a subshell. (If you then `exec` one of the processes from the subshell, you're not taking an efficiency loss in the branch where that line is reached since the `fork` used to spawn the subshell is the same one that would otherwise be going to run the subprocess). Thus:

```
(export VAR=value; exec1 & exec exec2)
(export VAR=value; exec1 && exec exec2)
(export VAR=value; exec1 || exec exec2)
(export VAR=value; exec1; exec exec2)
```

Obviously this is going to have undesired side effects if either of your commands were not actually external but were a shell builtin.

---

However, my advice? Don't. This makes your code less readable for very, very little gain. Repeating yourself isn't the end of the world in this case.

Comment: Forking to a subprocess can also lead to unexpected results.  For example, an `exit` in a subprocess only stops that subprocess, not the main script.  Additionally, extracting return codes from a subprocess can be challenging.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, that's covered in the "undesired side effects if either of your commands were not actually external" caveat; `exit`, after all, being a builtin.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, ...as for return codes, the subprocess exits with exit status of the last command it ran -- and when `exec` is used, of course, the command's exit status is passed through directly; the only case that's going to be trouble here is that where a component was backgrounded.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In my case I want to create an `alias` in my `.bashrc` for a command that I often have to repeat and it is complex. If I were to use it in a script the solution would be trivial to split in in more lines of code.

Comment: Using shell functions is better practice than aliases regardless -- much more powerful, as they can actually do conditional logic based on arguments -- and moreover, they prevent you from having code-length concerns.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay, ...if you were inclined to show your alias here, I'd be happy to demonstrate how to rewrite it as a function.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `export JSON=$(gcloud compute instances list --format json); gcloud compute ssh gabipetrovay@$(node --eval "console.log(JSON.parse(process.env.JSON)[0].name)") --zone $(node --eval "console.log(JSON.parse(process.env.JSON)[0].zone)"); unset JSON`. This is just one example I have right away (but there was one that involved several `gcloud` calls and I wanted to avoid the slow `gcloud` calls returning results necessary for further commands)

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay, I would have written that something like this: https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/69833beb5704e3592c4a -- structure the command right, and you don't need your variables to be in the environment.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay, ...also note that a function's "local" gives you a whole new scope, so you don't need to worry about overwriting like-named variables on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

This may get messy with quoting hell: group the commands to call in a subshell

```
VAR=value sh -c 'exec1 & exec2'
```

Comment: This is significantly less efficient than the subshell approach, since it's `exec`ing a new shell instance -- and to what end? (Also, it means you can't access any non-exported variables in forming your commands, unless expanding them into code and thus introducing `eval`-equivalent security risk).

Comment: I would argue with "significant" (what's really the cost of spawning sh). However, this answer is not largely different from yours.

Comment: If you're doing it in an inner loop, the cost of spawning sh adds up very quickly. (Then again, one would want to avoid forks there too -- and use of external commands).